# HA PostgreSQL installation using patroni and pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, clustering, pgbouncer, patroni

I'm not having a problem yet, just searching for advise

I want to build installation of PostgreSQL on 3 nodes using `patroni`: master and 2 standbys (for failover only). There are PostgreSQL and `pgbouncer` on each node with same configuration. All applications connect to PostgreSQL via `pgbouncer`

If PostgreSQL becomes dead, `patroni` automatically promotes on of the standbys as new master and everything just works fine. But if `pgbouncer` becomes dead nothing will happen

Is there any good way to make `patroni` watch `pgbouncer` (like it is doing for PostgreSQL) or I shouldn't use `patroni` for this case? What should I use?

I'm really not sure that it is what I want (cause `pgbouncer` is pretty stable), but here is my considerations:
- If `pgbouncer` becomes dead, entire node becomes useless for applications. So from application point of view it is the same as PostgreSQL becomes dead
- I don't really care about type of failure, even if `pgbouncer` restart could fix everything, so standby promotions suits me well

How do I suppose to solve problems like this?

Comment: Configuring systemd to restart pgbouncer might be the easiest option.... `Restart=on-failure` in the .service file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Consul templates for this. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template This will notify pgbouncer that Patroni has elected a new master.
Cheers,
Dave

Comment: This answer might be improved by a "how-to" based on what's in the link. Link-only answers are not really considered the best form of answer here.

Comment: Sure, I'll get an example up here soon..